# Counting entries with Python dictionary datatype

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning Python and writing a program that keeps track of the total number of various types of file extensions. I think a dictionary would be the perfect data type to track this information, something like:

```
.txt  14
.c    27
.java 12
```

I have some code written that builds a set, which eliminates duplicate file extensions, but how would I use a dictionary in Python to do the same thing but keep track of the number of occurances?

```
ext_list = set()
for i in file_list:
    ext_list.add(i.extension)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.7 or above, you can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(i.extension for i in file_list)
print(c)
```

`Counter` is a class derived from the standard Python `dict`.

If you prefer to use a plain `dict`, you can take advantage of its `setdefault()` method:

```
counts = {}
for i in file_list:
    counts.setdefault(i.extension, 0)
    counts[i.extension] += 1
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 7 seconds. +1.

Comment: Python 2.7 or 3.1+ - I don't believe it was available in 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
ext_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in file_list:
  ext_count[i.extension] += 1
```